# How to properly call solidity mapping in ethers.js?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, react

Hello I've been trying to ask question in discord, reddit, and no one them can answer

I'm still struggling for more than a week to call function in web3 react;
I have correctly abi, and always able to mint first,
i have this mapping on contract;

```
mapping(address => uint256[]) public userOwnedTokens;
```

and I call it like this:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum); 
const signer = provider.getSigner();   
const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(nftContractAddress,NFT.abi,signer  );  
let nftTx = await nftContract.userOwnedTokens.call(currentAccount);  
let nftTx2 = await nftContract.userOwnedTokens.methods.call(currentAccount);  
let nftTx3 = await nftContract.userOwnedTokens(currentAccount);   
console.log(nftTx1, nftTx2, nftTx3 "nftTx");
```

but it seems no working at all? what’s the proper way?

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')
also how do I get the list of all NFTS that been minted from all users? from ERC721
```

surely when using `_mint` , it will store in somewhere, but how do i get the list data? I want to show it for marketplace.

or this version, because mapping returns an array:

```
let nftx = [];
let index = 0;
while(true){    
  let x = await nftContract.userOwnedTokens(currentAccount, index).call();  
  if(x){
    nftx.push(x);
  }else{
    break;
  }
  index++;
}
console.log(nftx);
```

and nope nothing works,

people keep throwing answer without able explaining the usage with `method` and `call()`
or a need of axios.get() after executing function from wait() after executing function from contract

```
let tokenUri = await nftContract.tokenURI(tokenId);
let data = await axios.get(tokenUri);
```

or

```
  let nftTx = await nftContract.createEternalNFT();
  let tx = await nftTx.wait();
```

It is almost 2 weeks and none can explain, I have the source in this `https://gitlab.com/dellwatson/test`, after the contract-compile, copy the abi json into `client/utils/...json`

this is a simple nft mint;

Answer (score 3):

From the `userOwnedTokens` definition

```
mapping(address => uint256[]) public userOwnedTokens;
```

The solidity will create a public getter that has this signature `userOwnedTokens(address,uint256) public view returns (uint256)`. If you want to get the whole array you have to create your own getter.

```
function foo(address addr) public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
    return userOwnedTokens[addr];
}
```

To call a view function follow the [documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract--readonly).

```
let nfts = await nftContract.foo(currentAccount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
```

must be

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
```